# Importing word document with column breaks into indesign with page breaks

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to make subtitles using indesign for use in premiere pro. I have written out all the subtitles I want in word with column breaks separating the lines and I want to import this into indesign so each text set appears on a new page - as seen in this video: https://vimeo.com/80445034

At the moment I am getting one page with the first subtitle in view and the rest of the subtitles are in the text box but can only be seen by deleting the column breaks.

How do you get indesign to recognise column breaks as page breaks and make multiple pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes importing texts from word to indesign gives you undesired page/column breaks. It's something unavoidable but easily fixed. 
**You have to use the "find and replace" window.** 
I always start with finding double line breaks and replacing them with only one line break, run that again and again until you don't have any double line breaks left. Do the same with any column breaks that are double or tippled, and If you don't want the at all just find and replace with line break or nothing at all.
You also sure make sure your paragraph style has all of the details you need:
Title Settings
Subtitle Settings
High Leading between Subtitle and the title that comes right after it so that they never go in the same box